# how avoid dublicate data to mysql

Tags: python, sql, sql-update, mariadb, sql-insert

I write the code to **scrape** car info(title, make, model, transmission, year, price) data from ebay.com and save in the mysql,
I want if all row's(title, make, model, ...) item's is be similar to another row  then avoid to insert this data to the mysql, *only when all row's item be similar(because some title is simialr or some model or...)

code :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import mysql.connector

conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='******', 
host='127.0.0.1', database='web_scraping')
cursor = conn.cursor()
url = 'https://www.ebay.com/b/Cars-Trucks/6001?_ fsrp=0&_sacat=6001&LH_BIN=1&LH_ItemCondition=3000%7C1000%7C2500&rt=nc&_stpos=95125&Model%2520Year=2020%7C2019%7C2018%7C2017%7C2016%7C2015'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
ebay_cars = soup.find_all('li', class_='s-item')
for car_info in ebay_cars:
    title_div = car_info.find('div', class_='s-item__wrapper clearfix')
    title_sub_div = title_div.find('div', class_='s-item__info clearfix')
    title_p = title_sub_div.find('span', class_='s-item__price')
    title_tag = title_sub_div.find('a', class_='s-item__link')
    title_maker = title_sub_div.find('span', class_='s-item__dynamic s- 
    item__dynamicAttributes1')
    title_model = title_sub_div.find('span', class_='s-item__dynamic s- 
    item__dynamicAttributes2')
    title_trans = title_sub_div.find('span', class_='s-item__dynamic s- 
    item__dynamicAttributes3')



name_of_car = re.sub(r'\d{4}', '', title_tag.text)
maker_of_car = re.sub(r'Make: ','', title_maker.text)
model_of_car = re.sub(r'Model: ', '', title_model.text)
try:
    if title_trans.text.startswith(r'Transmission: '):
        trans_of_car = re.sub(r'Transmission: ', '', title_trans.text)
    else:
        trans_of_car = ''
except AttributeError:
    trans_of_car = ''
year_of_car = re.findall(r'\d{4}', title_tag.text)
year_of_car = ''.join(str(x) for x in year_of_car)

price_of_car = title_p.text
print(name_of_car ,trans_of_car )
sql = 'INSERT INTO car_info(Title, Maker, Model, Transmission, Year, Price) 
VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'
cursor.execute(sql , (name_of_car, maker_of_car, model_of_car, trans_of_car, 
year_of_car, price_of_car))



conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

One option uses `not exists`:

```
insert into car_info (title, maker, model, transmission, year, price) 
select v.*
from (select %s title, %s maker, %s model, %s transmission, %s year, %s price) v
where not exists (
    select 1
    from car_info c
    where 
        (c.title, c.maker, c.model, c.transmission, c.year, c.price)
         = (v.title, v.maker, v.model, v.transmission, v.year, v.price)
);
```

But it would be simpler to create a unique key on all columns of the table, like:

```
create unique index idx_car_info_uniq
    on car_info(title, maker, model, transmission, year, price);
```

This prevents any process from inserting duplicates in the table. You can elegantly ignore the erros that would otherwise have been raised with the `on duplicate key` syntax:

```
insert into car_info (title, maker, model, transmission, year, price) 
values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
on duplicate key update title = values(title);
```

Comment: Try simpler way but show this error: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
on duplicate key update Title = values(Title)' at line 2

Answer (score 1):

You could save the result of this query into a variable

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM car_info WHERE Title = <titleValue>, Maker = <makerValue>, Model = <modelValue>, Transmission = <transmisionValue>, Year = <yearValue>, Price = <priceValue>
```

and then, if the value of the variable is

- 1, you skip the INSERT because you already have this entry in the table
- 0, you make the INSERT because you do not have that entry in the table

It's just one way of doing this.

Comment: sorry, i'm beginner in python, can you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

declare the primary key as all the columns in the table. See: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-primary-key/

Comment: can you expali about your idea(You could save the result of this query into a variable) i think just that work, i try another but not work, bucase I want when all inserted data in row(include title, make, model, transsmission, year, pirce) is similar then prevent to insert that data , becuase some title or model or maker of cars is similar(I tryed unipue or primary key but

Comment: If you declare in mysql that the primary ket of a table is to be all the columns of that table then mysql will prevent all attempts to store a row that is equal to any row already in the table. It is one of the most important restrictions in a database as the primary key is there to uniquely identify a row in a table. No need to save anything, just make sql statement to store the row into the database and then mysql will refuse to store it if it is a double. You get an error, which you catch in your Python program, that's all. see @GMB post.